# How to check if imageview is currently zoomed or not in android?

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

i am zooming an image view on double tap to some certain points. on double tap event it zooms in perfectly but i want to implement the functionality of zoom out too that when user double taps the image is zoomed but when he double tap again the zoomed image must go back to original size
how this can be done? Any help will be appreciated
Here is my code

```
 ImageView iv;
 private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
 getResources(), R.drawable.demoimg), size.x, size.y, true);
 iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
 original_matrix = iv.getImageMatrix();
 iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(SecondActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                float scalefactor = Math.max(1.1f, Math.min(3.0f, 4.0f));
                float x = e.getX();
                float y = e.getY();
                matrix.setScale(scalefactor, scalefactor, x, y);
                iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);


            }

        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On Touch Event Called",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: zomm effect is working ??

Comment: yes it zooms in perfectly...now i want to zoom out on double tap. i mean there may be a check that will check if its zoomed in currenlty then on double tap set back to original postion

Comment: above code is not working with my case..not zoomed

Comment: its working on double tap in my case :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to Extend the imageView and make your customImageView.

In your customImageView keep the original size of your image and the track of image current state (zoomed in/out) then in your xml use your customImageView instead of android imageView .

You can put your zoom method in your customImageView. Then you have a customImageView which know how to zoom in, get back to the original size and its current state.

Comment: i got your point but my confusion is how to keep the track of image current state?

Comment: Add a boolean field in your customImageView like "isZoomedIn" with a default false value then whenever the zoom method was called check that if its false so image needs to be zoomed in and that must be chanhed to be set as true and whenever its true image must be zoomed out and it must be set as false.

Comment: Hmm i tried this but by doing this my image is not evening zooming in now :(

Comment: Put what you did in your question.

Comment: private Matrix original_matrix = new Matrix();
    boolean check_zoom_state = false;

Comment: iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        original_matrix = iv.getImageMatrix();

Comment: iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(SecondActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                    if (check_zoom_state == false) {
                        float scalefactor = Math.max(1.1f, Math.min(3.0f, 4.0f));
                        float x = e.getX();
                        float y = e.getY();

Comment: matrix.setScale(scalefactor, scalefactor, x, y);
                        iv.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                        check_zoom_state = true;
                    } else {
                        iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix);
                    }

                    return super.onDoubleTap(e);


                }

            });

Comment: In else set the checkzoomstate false again.

Comment: Put the checkzoomstate inside simpleOnGestureListener() outside onDoubleTap.

Comment: you mean i should set it to true outside double tap?

Comment: No i mean "boolean checkZoomState = false" must go into simpleOnGestureListener but outside onDoubleTap.

Comment: yes i pasted it withing simpleOnGestureListener, still i was not working then i wrote iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true); instead of iv.setImageMatrix(original_matrix); and that works but it works for one time only. i mean when i double tap for the first time image zooms in on second time it zooms out but after that it never zooms in